# Django template doesn't load

Tags: python, django, templates, django-templates, django-views

Am following the Django Website's tutorial, currently on Pt3(https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/intro/tutorial03/)

Tutorial states: "This code should create a bulleted-list containing the “What’s up” question from Tutorial 2. The link points to the question’s detail page."
After adding the template and running the server I still only see this 
[previous page and no updated template](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lEBsA.png)
, what's wrong here? Thanks for your help!

**django_proj/mysite/mysite/urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
url(r'^polls/', include('polls.urls')),
url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

**django_proj/mysite/polls/urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    #ex: /polls/
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),

    # ex: /polls/5/
    url(r'^(?P<question_id>[0-9]+)/$', views.detail, name='detail'),

    # ex: /polls/5/results/
    url(r'^(?P<question_id>[0-9]+)/results/$', views.results, name='results'),

    # ex: /polls/5/vote/
    url(r'^(?P<question_id>[0-9]+)/vote/$', views.vote, name='vote'),
]
```

**django_proj/mysite/polls/views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
    from django.http import HttpResponse
from .models import Question



def index(request):
    latest_question_list = Question.objects.order_by('-pub_date')[:5]
    template = loader.get_template('polls/index.html')
    context = {
        'latest_question_list': latest_question_list,
    }
    return HttpResponse(template.render(context, request))

def detail(request, question_id):
        return HttpResponse("You're looking at question %s." % question_id)

def results(request, question_id):
        response = "You're looking at the results of question %s."
        return HttpResponse(response %  question_id)

def vote(request, question_id):
        return HttpResponse("You're voting on question %s." % question_id)
def index(request):
        return HttpResponse("At Polls Index")
```

**/django_proj/mysite/polls/templates/polls/index.html**

```
{% if latest_question_list %}
<ul>
{% for question in latest_question_list %}
    <li><a href="/polls/{{ question.id }}/">{{ question.question_text }}</a></li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
{% else %}
<p>No polls are available.</p>
{% endif %}
```

Similar problem to: [Django Template not loading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32076207/django-template-not-loading)

Comment: add `project urls.py`

Comment: Hi Astik, where should I add it?

Comment: Here only add in question.

Comment: @AstikAnand Sorry not following, do you mean in the urls.py or views.py? Where exactly?

Comment: I mean here you also add `project urls.py` as you have added `index.html`, `views.py` and `urls.py`.

Comment: Oh I see I will add it!

Comment: @AstikAnand Added as 1st example

Comment: Remove the last def index(request), it is no longer needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `views.py` **remove** this, coz you have defined it 2 times.

```
def index(request):
    return HttpResponse("At Polls Index")
```

Comment: @jamarcus_13, Have you tried?? Did it worked for you?

Comment: Perfect! Works fine ~ embarassing error but thanks for your help.

Comment: There is nothing to embarass, It happens when we start learning.